# Is there a way to link two nodes in Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to have two peers within an organization in which one peer act as a client that only send transactions without storing the ledger, and the other act as normal peer. I read about having lightweight node and full node. But how to make them both related to the same organization in Hyperledger?

Answer (score 1):

All peer nodes are committers in Hyperledger Fabric. Thus, every peer node stores the ledger. If a node does not store the ledger, it may be a client or some kind of proxy, but not a peer node. Please, refer to the document where you have read about lightweight and full nodes, as it may be not referring to peers.

Anyway, every node is related to its organization through its [MSP](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/msp.html).